# How to rename an existing Hybris extension

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on Hybris and I generated a new extension using hybris command (ant extgen) with default settings. During extension generation, I did not change default values like I let the project name to be "training". I started developing some code just for the sake of trying it but now I wrote quite a lot of code and instead of generating a new extension, I am trying to rename "training" to a new name which is more suitable for my project.

My question is - Is there any shortcut to rename "training" to a new name. By rename I don't mean standard intellij or eclipse module rename but also updating all extension specific properties which are referring to extension name "training". Is there any hybris ant command for it?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736566/2478134) is the way I can think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. It might also be easier just to create a new one and move the code into the new extension.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is the way I can think of.**
You can declare your extension as a template for `extgen` and then generate a new extension based on it with a new name and structure.

Let me take `training` as your current extension which you want to convert to some other name. Below are the steps you need to perform.

1. Make sure your extension (training) is there in the **localextensions.xml**
2. Update extensioninfo.xml to mark the extension as a template by adding below meta tag

   `<meta key="extgen-template-extension" value="true"/>`

   Look like

   ```
     <coremodule generated="true" manager="org.training.jalo.TrainingManager" packageroot="org.training"/>
     <meta key="extgen-template-extension" value="true"/>
     <webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/training"/>
   ```
3. Create an extgen.properties inside training extension/folder with below properties

   Please note, If your current extension is with a different name then training in that case you need to change below values accordingly.

   **extgen.properties:**

   `YEXTNAME_TOKEN=training

   YMODULE_TOKEN=training

   YMODULE_PACKAGE_ROOT=training

   YMODULE_CLASS_PREFIX=training

   YPACKAGE_TOKEN=org.training

   YMANAGER_TOKEN=TrainingManager

   YCLASSPREFIX_TOKEN=Training

   YGENERATED_TOKEN=Generated`
4. Run **ant extgen** and select your extension (training) from the given selection option and give the name and package the way you want when it prompt for it.
5. Now replace training extension with the newly created extension inside localextensions.xml
6. Test and patch wherever needed! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it but it is a long path I did not get chance to try it. I copied code in new renamed extension and it worked. thanks.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, especially if u have a big extension with lots of code.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. The generated extension itself was created from a template where the word "training" is inserted into many places (class names, package names, configurations...) .

The other approach would be to look into the ext-template folder (6.7). There are all templates. Search for any token in the templates and make appropriate change in your generated extensions.
Depending on the amount of your extensions, it will also take some time... and you need to understand how extgen works, first.